# Can men have women shave their peyot/beard

Tags: halacha, women, yoreh-deah, shaving, payot-sideburns

According to Halacha, 2 of the three negative commandments that don’t apply to women are shaving Peyot and shaving the corners of beards. My question is, is it permissible for a Jewish man to ask a Jewish woman to shave their peyot/beard corner, based on the principle women are not included injunction against it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Straight Shulchan Aruch, [Yorah De'ah 181:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.181.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> אשה אינה במצות הקפה וי"א שאף על פי שמותרת להקיף פאת ראשה אסורה להקיף
> פאת ראש האיש ואפילו הוא קטן:
>
> A woman is not included in the mitzvah of rounding, but there are
> those who say that although she is permitted to round the corner of
> her head, she is forbidden to round the corner of the head of a man,
> even if he is a minor.

and [ibid 12](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.181.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> אשה שיש לה זקן מותרת להשחיתו ודינה בהשחתת זקן האיש כדינה בהקפת ראש
> האיש:
>
> A woman who has a beard is permitted to destroy it; and the law for
> her in destroying the beard of a man is the same as in rounding the
> head of a man.

---

What about the man who asks? [Ibid 4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.181.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> גם הניקף חייב אם סייע בדבר שמטה עצמו אליו להקיפו אבל איסורא איכא אע"פ
> שלא סייע לפיכך אסור להיות ניקף אפילו על ידי עובד כוכבים:
>
> The person whose pe'ot are shaved off is also liable if he assists in
> shaving, leaning his head to him so that he shaves his pe'ah, but
> there is prohibition even if he does not help, therefore it is
> forbidden to have one's pe'ot shaved off even by means of an idolater.

Comment: "but there is prohibition even if he does not help".  Can one violate a prohibition while being passive and not doing an action? (Assuming he stands still while the idolater shaves)

Comment: @user9806 follow the gemara to [Makkot](https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.20b.7?lang=bi). Rabbi Yehuda (whose opinion this is) holds that a person can be flogged for a passive action prohibition